# How do i know if in app purchase works in my app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a game were you have the opportunity to unlock content by in app purchase. But the app is not published yet because i don't know if my in app purchase really works. So the question is: How can i be 100 % sure that the in app purchase function works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is going to itunesConnect and creating a test user. For this just log in and look for the manage user accounts option.

Once you have done that, go to Settings/Store on your device and log out from your current user. Do not yet log in with the test user you created at the step above.

Then, in you app, go and buy your feature. The app will prompt for username/password; specify those for the new test user.

That's it.

Answer (score 3):

iTunes connect will let you set up a sandboxed environment that you can test purchases against [See the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html)